# Lebesgue number proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is a proof I found from Marsden's Elementary classical analysis but there's a part I don't understand.

Lemma: Assume that $A$ is sequentially compact. Let ${U_i}$ be an open cover of$A$.
Then there is a $r >0$ such that for each $y \in A$, $B(y,r) \subset U_i$ for some $U_i$. The number $r$ is called a Lebesgue number for the covering.

Proof) If not, then for every integer n, there is some $y_n$ such that $B(y_n,1/n)$ is not contained in any $U_i$. By hypothesis, $y_n$ has a convergent subsequence say, $z_n$ that converges to $z \in A$. Since the $U_i$ cover $A$, $z \in U_{i0}$ for some $U_{i0}$.
Choose $e>0$ such that $B(z,e) \subset U_{i0}$. Choose $N$ large enough so that $d(z_N,z) < e/2$ and $1/N<e/2$. **Then $B(z_N,1/N) \subset U_{i0}$, a contradiction.**

I don't see how the last sentence, which is bolded, is a contradiction. To get a contradiction, isn't it necessary to show that there is an integer $N$ such that for all $y_n$, $B(y_n,1/n)$ is contained in any $U_i$? How does this conclusion lead to this contradiction?

Comment: The construction starts with a sequence such that _no_ $B(y_n,1/n)$ is contained in _any_ $U_i$. But further on, you see that _all_ $B(z_N,1/N)$ - and each of these is a $B(y_{n_k},1/n_k)$ - for large enough $N$ are in fact contained in some $U_i$.

Comment: See the assumption: there is some $y_n$ such that $B(y_n,1/n)$ is not contained in any $U_i$. So it's enough to show that there must be at least one $B(z_N, 1/N)$ which is contained by some $U_{i0}$.